java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type
Es una app Spring batch que simplemente accede a una bd recoge datos de una tabla y los saca en un archivo.
El mysql-connector-java lo tengo como runtime
Revise por posibles conflictos por conectores de bd ya que antes tenía h2 pero la eliminé
`@Configuration
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchConfiguration {
@Autowired
JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

@Autowired
JobRepository jobRepository;

@Autowired
SessionFactory sessionFactory;

@Autowired
@Qualifier("mysql1DataSource")
DataSource mysql1DataSource;


@Bean
public Job job (Step step1){
    return jobBuilderFactory.get("xml")
            .repository(jobRepository)
            .start(step1)
            .build();
}
@Bean
public Step step1(PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager){
    return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
            .transactionManager(transactionManager)
            .<Persona,Persona>chunk(10)
            .reader(readerBD())
            .writer(writer())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public ItemWriter<Persona> writer(){
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Persona>()
            .name("write")
            .resource(new FileSystemResource("out.csv"))
            .delimited()
            .delimiter("|")
            .names(new String[] {"Nombre","Apellido","Edad"})
            .build();

}

Configuración Datasource
@Configuration
public class DataSourcesConfig {
@Bean
@Primary
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource.mysql1")
public DataSource mysql1DataSource(){
    return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
}

application.properties:
spring.datasource.mysql1.url=jdbc:mysql://mysql1:3306/Personas
spring.datasource.mysql1.username=root
spring.datasource.mysql1.password=password1
spring.datasource.mysql1.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect

El error que me da es este:
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'batchDataSourceInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration$DataSourceInitializerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.BatchDataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer]: Factory method 'batchDataSourceInitializer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to detect database type


Comprobe la bd desde un cliente y se conecta bien
